# How can I run a script when a div is a certain distance from the top of the page?

Tags: jquery

I have a script that almost works. I am trying to execute a javascript function when a div is a certain distance from the top of the page. The div will change position when the user scrolls the page, and I want to calculate its distance from the top. Here is what I have:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var myDiv = $("#myDiv").offset().top;
    var height = $(window).height();
    if(myDiv < height)
    {
        myScript();
    }
});
```

The problem is that this script only runs after I have scrolled all the way down on the page. This happens even if I write:

```
var myDiv = parseInt($("#myDiv").offset().top) - 300;
```

It seems that `myDiv < height` isn't really working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($("#myDiv").scrollTop() < height ) {
        myFunction();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still has the same effect. It's weird b/c it still does the same thing even if I write ``if(100 < height)``.

Comment: please include a fiddle or link, i cant help without one.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(window).scroll(function () {
     var scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop;
     var offsetTop = $("#myDiv").offset().top;
     var offsetHeight = $("#myDiv").height();

     if(scrollTop + $(window).height() >= offsetTop && scrollTop < offsetTop + offsetHeight) {
         myScript();
     }
 });
```

Basically...

If the scroll position + the window's height is greater to or equal to the div's top, and the document's scroll position is greater than the bottom of the div, fire myScript.

If the div is visible, it should fire myScript.

I used document.body.scrollTop because if I used $("body").scrollTop(), Firefox would always return 0. If you want, you could use $("body").scrollTop() || $("html").scrollTop().